# Parse query mdb on php

Tags: php, ms-access

I have code like these

```
<?php
    $mdb_file = realpath('../PEB_MDB/dbPEB.mdb');
    $dsn='Driver={MSAccess};DBQ='.$mdb_file.';';
    //$mdb_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/sapfiles/web_supp/PEB_MDB/dbPEB.mdb";
    $user = "";
    $password = "MumtazFarisHana";
    $conn = odbc_connect($dsn,$user,$password);

    var_dump($conn);

    $sql = "SELECT a.NAMABELI,s.URBRG1,a.NAMABELI,a.NEGBELI,a.NEGTUJU,a.CAR,a.KDKTR,a.PELMUAT,
        a.NODAFT,a.TGDAFT,a.FOB,d.NoDok,d.TgDok FROM (tblpebhdr AS a INNER JOIN tblpebdok AS d 
        ON a.CAR = d.CAR) INNER JOIN tblpebdtl AS s ON a.CAR = s.CAR 
        WHERE d.KdDok='380' and a.TGDAFT>=#01/jan/2018# AND a.TGDAFT<=#01/Apr/2018#";
    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql) or die(odbc_errormsg());
    var_dump($rs);
?>
```

When I try running these code, it said `Couldn't parse SQL`, if I change my query like `SELECT * FROM tblpebhdr` it working prefectly, But why my first query didn't work at all? Is because the hashtag (#)? or something else?

Comment: Why are you using parentheses?

Comment: user3685048 umm... what do you mean??

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct Access SQL syntax, so try to remove one field at the time and you should find the offending field name.

Also, never use text months in filters as the names are expected to be localised, and - while the "reverse" US format is accepted, thus can't be the source of your error, if TGDAFT is of data type DateTime - make it a habit to use the ISO sequence yyyy-mm-dd:

```
a.TGDAFT>=#2018/01/01# AND a.TGDAFT<=#2018/04/01#";
```